# Does geb rollback the database to its virgin state after every each test?

Tags: grails, geb

I've been getting my feet wet with Geb on Grails, but there's not a lot of documentation about how it behaves. For instance, how does geb handle rollbacks? From what I'm observing, it runs the app and runs the test on the browser itself without turning it off in between tests.

What happens to the database data when one spec (spec A) alters an object (object Z), and a few tests later, another spec(spec B) alters the same object? Does geb rollback the database to it's virgin state every time a spec is ran? I'm trying to confirm because I have geb tests that ran fine when executed individually, but when I ran them as a suite, some of them fails, and the best reason I could come up with is the data isn't in pristine condition when a second test was run on it. Any thoughts?

Comment: It depends on how you had configured your build.gradle file!

Comment: You might want to check out the [remote-control plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/remote-control). You can use it to query and manipulate the database during your @Stepwise functional tests. For example, I use it for testing new account registration. The app sends a verification email to the new user with a URL to activate the account. I retrieve that URL from the database and "verify" the new account inside a Geb test.

Answer (score 7):

Geb tests and functional tests in general are quite different from unit and integration tests. Unit and integration tests run in the same JVM, and the test runner starts a transaction before each test and rolls it back after the test runs, which has the effect of resetting the database but in reality it's just keeping tests from changing the database. But any data inserted into the database before the tests start (e.g. from BootStrap) will be there for each test.

But functional tests are typically run in one JVM but they make remote calls to your app running in a second JVM. This limits what you can do during tests, for example you can't manipulate metaclasses, or change Spring bean instance variables, and you can't start and rollback transactions to isolate data changes between tests. You can do any of those things, but they would affect the local JVM only.

Geb could remotely make these changes of course, but that would require modifying your application to add a controller or some other way of making remote calls, but it doesn't.

In general tests shouldn't be ordered and should be independent, but I find that when doing functional tests that it makes sense to break that rule and order them, where an earlier test does some inserts or other changes and later tests do further work and/or checks based on earlier changes. I've also added test-only controller actions that can be used to roll back changes (via a transaction or by deleting inserted data, undoing updates and deletes, etc.) and make other changes to assist the tests, but this has to be done carefully to ensure that it is only available during testing and doesn't become a significant security risk.

Comment: I always suggest using [Grails Remote Control plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/remote-control) (or [Groovy Remote Control](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/remote/) when the application under test is not written in Grails) cause in my opinion it's best to keep your fixture code as close to the tests as possible and fixture controllers don't really fit that description.